# SQL date update query for sequential times

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a database with a date field in text format. 
I want to update some of dates in my table. So, basically, the current date should change to new date, the thing is that I have at least 1000 records that need to be updated. The only advantage is that time in my date field is sequential.

I tried the following query:

```
UPDATE my_table set Date='05-10-2012 00:00:00' WHERE Date like '%04-26-2012%'
```

but, it neglects the time section in my date field.

To illustrate of my intent

```
    Current Date                     New Date
04-26-2012 02:45:00             05-10-2012 01:19:00
04-26-2012 02:47:00             05-10-2012 01:20:00
04-26-2012 02:48:00             05-10-2012 01:21:00
04-26-2012 02:49:00             05-10-2012 01:22:00
04-26-2012 02:50:00             05-10-2012 01:23:00
```

So, How can I update my date to the new date with the time section that I want ?

Comment: so, are you also changing the time portion to start from a certain minute?

Comment: Where are you getting the Time portion from?

Comment: yes, the new time portion should start from 01:19:00 and it should increase 1 minute for each record

Comment: that makes things harder, are you on SQL Server 2005 or above?

Comment: yes, I am using sql server 2008

Comment: `WHERE [Date] LIKE '%string%'` oh dear...

Comment: Please see why you shouldn't use `[Date] LIKE '%string%'`: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5b64f/4 Or, if your "Date" column is being stored as a string, stop doing that. Much better treatment of the topic here: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mishandling-date-range-queries.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a variable before your update statement. To a minute before your starting time.  Then increment the variable in the update statement before setting the field.  I have pasted an example below.

```
declare @testData table (oldDate datetime)

insert into @testData (oldDate) values ('04-26-2012 02:45:00')

insert into @testData (oldDate) values ('04-26-2012 02:47:00')

insert into @testData (oldDate) values ('04-26-2012 02:48:00')

insert into @testData (oldDate) values ('04-26-2012 02:49:00')

insert into @testData (oldDate) values ('04-26-2012 02:50:00')


-- Set a default start date.

declare @newStartDate as dateTime

set @newStartDate = '05-10-2012 01:18:00'



update @testData set @newStartDate = DATEADD(MINUTE,1,@newStartDate),
    oldDate = @newStartDate

select * from @testData
```

Answer (score 1):

all data type issues aside, here ya go...

```
declare @from datetime, @thru datetime, @dateSeed datetime;
set @from = '4/26/2012';
set @thru = '4/27/2012';
set @dateSeed = '5/10/2012 1:19:00';

with cte as (
    select
        Date,
        rn = row_number() over(order by Date)
    from
        my_table
    where
            Date >= @from and Date < @thru
        --Date like '%04-26-2012%'
)

update cte set
    --110 = USA m/d/y format + 108 = hh:mm:ss 24 hour format
    --Date = convert(varchar(10), dateadd(mi, rn-1, @dateSeed), 110) + ' ' + convert(varchar(8), dateadd(mi, rn-1, @dateSeed), 108)
   Date = dateadd(mi, rn-1, @dateSeed)
```

Comment: Have you tested `where Date like '%04-26-2012%'`? Against what data type?

Comment: OP said `Date` is varchar...just copied from his example

Comment: Not sure I agree "date field in text format" necessarily means it is a varchar column. My interpretation is a date column and what he sees when he does SELECT * is as he's shown.

Comment: Also, please don't `convert(varchar` without a length! https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx

Comment: Also, it should be noted (for future viewers) that this won't handle ranges over multiple years, with string dates in the given format (although it should work for the problem as defined).